# Using Cauchy’s MVT show that $f(b)=f(a)+f'(a)(b-a)+\cdots+\frac{f^{(n-1)}(a)}{(n-1) !}(b-a)^{n-1}+\frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{(n) !}(b-a)^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

Using Cauchy’s MVT show that if

> $f',f'',f'''...f^{(n-1)}$ exists and are continuos in $[a,b]$ and$f^{(n)}$ is defined in $(a,b)$ then exists $\xi \in(a, b)$ such that
> $$f(b)=f(a)+f^{\prime}(a)(b-a)+\frac{f^{\prime \prime}(a)}{2}(b-a)^{2}+\cdots+\frac{f^{(n-1)}(a)}{(n-1) !}(b-a)^{n-1}+\frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{(n) !}(b-a)^{n}$$

I don't have any idea in how to do it, but i've seen that some people define

$\displaystyle F(x)=f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k !}(x-a)^{k}$

$G(x)=(x-a)^{n}$

but I  don't understand, any help? thank you!

Comment: You’ll find the proof in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1):

From the F.T.C.
$$\int^x_a{f'(v)dv}=f(x)-f(a)$$
For
$$\int^x_a{f'(v)dv}$$
Integrate by parts

$$
\int^x_a{f'(v)dv}=f'(a)(x-a)+\int^x_a{f''(v)(x-v)}dv 
$$

By repeated integration by parts
$$
\int^x_a{f'(v)dv}=f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)(x-a)^2}{2}+...\int^x_a{\frac{f^{n+1}(v)(x-v)^n}{n!}}dv 
$$

Returning to the top equation, we now have
$$
f(x) = f(a) +f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)(x-a)^2}{2}+...\int^x_a{\frac{f^{n+1}(v)(x-v)^n}{n!}}dv
$$

To evaluate

$$
\int^x_a{\frac{f^{n+1}(v)(x-v)^n}{n!}}dv
$$

We use the second M.V.T. for integrals:
$$\int^b_a{f(v)g(v)dv}=f(\xi)\int^b_a{g(v)dv}$$ for some constant $\xi \in (a,b)$

Application to the original equation yields

$$
f(x) = f(a) +f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)(x-a)^2}{2}+...{f^{n+1}(\xi)}\int^x_a{\frac{(x-v)^n }{n!}}dv
$$

Finally
$$
f(x) = f(a) +f(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)(x-a)^2}{2}+\dots{f^{n+1}(\xi)}\frac{(x-a)^{n+1} }{(n+1)!}dv
$$

where $\xi \in (a,b)$  as $x=b$ as intended

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be such that $F(b)-MG(b)=0$, and consider the function $H(x)=F(x)-MG(x)$. Then
$$
H(a)=H'(a)=H''(a)=\dots=H^{(n-1)}(a)=0 \quad \text{and} \quad H(b)=0.
$$

Let $b_0=b$, then $H(a)=H(b_0)=0$. By Rolle's Theorem, there exists $b_1\in(a,b_0)$ such that $H'(b_1)=0$. But then $H'(a)=H'(b_1)=0$, so we can repeat this step $n-1$ times to find
$$
a<b_{n-1}<b_{n-2}<\dots<b_1<b_0=b
$$
such that for all $k=0,1,\dots,n-1$, we have $H^{(k)}(b_k)=0$. (More rigorously, it's a sub-proof by induction.)

Finally, $H^{(n-1)}(a)=H^{(n-1)}(b_{n-1})=0$, so there exists $\xi=b_n\in(a,b_{n-1})$ such that $H^{(n)}(\xi)=0$.

But $H^{(n)}(x)=F^{(n)}(x)-n!M=f^{(n)}(x)-n!M$, so
$$
0=H^{(n)}(\xi)=f^{(n)}(\xi)-n!M=0,
$$
i.e.
$$
M=\frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{n!} \quad \text{for some} \quad \xi\in(a,b).
$$